# cannot use stateserver mode other than inproc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, session-state, stateserver

The most irritating problem i've come across. I have an asp.net mvc application with sessionstate mode to stateserver. On my local machine and my old server iis6 it worked but i recently changed to a new server running iis7 and now the line:

```
 <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" timeout="20" />
```

doesn't do anything. Even when I set the value in the connectionstring to something that doesn't exist it is ignored and thus it's using inproc only.

All my webapps under iis have the same problem.

I've also tried sqlserver mode with the same result. it just gets ignored.

Why oh why??

Answer (score 0):

There's a place in IIS where you can disable InProcess session state.

These articles should point you in the right direction:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732964%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725624%28WS.10%29.aspx